# regular Expresssion matching the multple Alphanumeric characters separated by '-'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match a requirement ID which consists of alphanumeric character and then a '-' and this can occur one or multitple times.

The example string would be:

```
NXOS-ABCD-005-053 – Requirement No. 1
F56156-ISSU-1 - Requirement No 1
```

I tried the regex below using regex 101 website but could not get the appropriate result that i would require.

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+\-)*
```

My understanding of using the above regex is ; it will match all characters A-Za-z0-9 multiple times , followed by a - and this combination can occur one or more times.

But It gives me logs of groups which i dont anticipate.
can i get some help to fine tune the regex as I tried to google a lot but bot confused with various usages.
Any help towards this will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*`? Or, if it is not at the start of string, `\b[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*`? Note `([A-Za-z0-9]+\-)*` can match empty strings, as it matches any zero or more occurrences of a sequence of one or more alphanumeric chars followed with a hyphen. Note there is no hyphen after the last alphanumeric part, so this would not match the whole ID even if it worked as you think it would.

Comment: What in the above samples is your expected results?

Comment: * is _zero_ or more times. Also what you've described _wouldn't_ match the IDs. I'd recommend using e.g. https://regex101.com/.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `?:` it's unnecessary, no?
`/^[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*/i`

Comment: @Eduardo It depends. In Python, non-capturing groups are very convenient if you use `re.findall`. You are showing a JavaScript/Ruby/PHP regex literal notation now, but your question is tagged with Python, so I suggested just a string pattern in my top comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note `([A-Za-z0-9]+\-)*` can match empty strings, as it matches any zero or more occurrences of a sequence of one or more alphanumeric chars followed with a hyphen. Note there is no hyphen after the last alphanumeric part, so this would not match the whole ID even if it worked as you think it would.

I suggest

```py
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

Or, if it is not at the start of string

```py
\b[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptTyHL/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of the pattern sequence inside the [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions):

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. This work perfecttly fine.